# Haskell GUI application runs from Leksah, but crashes when .exe invoked from command line

Tags: haskell, leksah

When I *Run* the minimalistic program (listed below) from the Leksah IDE (version 0.16.2.2, on Win 7 64-bit system) the window opens correctly. But when the exe-file generated by Leksah is launched from the command line, some other window opens instead with the following message:

*Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np could not be located in the dynamic link library libwinpthread-1.dll.*

```hs
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main = do
   initGUI
   window <- windowNew
   widgetShowAll window
   mainGUI
```

(To build this code in Leksah, the package-related cabal file has to also contain `gtk3 -any` in the *build-depends* section.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from Hamishmack here: https://github.com/leksah/leksah/issues/442 :

Add leksah's bin directory to your `PATH` before launching the `.exe`. Something like:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Leksah\bin
```

Alternatively copy the missing DLL files from the `C:\Leksah\bin` directory into the same directory as your `.exe` file.